# three.js OrbitControls & keyframes

Tags: json, animation, three.js, blender

for my second test I use the blender export with textures an animation : it's a furniture with a drawer and a door : when the mouse is over facedrawer, action the drawer's animation and if the mouse over the door action chardoorsup animation.

01 : I have always the same problem with materials in js which are not applicate in html... I don't know how to call materials in js made by export three.js in blender...

02 : The OrbitControls isn't functional with activation of keyframe : bad code or bug ?

03 : the animation is normaly activate by mouseover (realized in blender with the logic editor ) but threejs take the blender logic editor ?  how much animation are exported ?

you see the code [HERE](http://www.macabann.com/THREEJS04/modiflapin06.html)

I tested my js on threefab, and the animations are playing together. the materials are not reading.

thank to answers

Comment: I have an error in console with last exporter blender : Horodatage : 01/01/2013 16:22:51
Avertissement : Error: WebGL: DrawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array
Fichier Source : https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js
Ligne : 20871

Comment: and with the exporter for blender 2.64 I haven't error. only object isn't display on firefox or chrome test